# undefined member.voiceChannel

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am having trouble with my discord bot not knowing what channel a user is in. If I check `member.voiceChannel` it always returns `undefined`. Even if I am inside a voice channel.

**Code:**

```js
let voiceChannel;

voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel;

if (!voiceChannel) {   
    return msg.reply('Please join a voice channel before using this command.');
}
```

`console.log(voiceChannel);` prints `undefined` regardless of me being in a Voice Channel or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happened to me just now while using Discord.js v12.

Apparently the variable changed names between versions and now instead of:

```
message.member.voiceChannel
```

It is:

```
message.member.voice.channel
```

Changing the variable like this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This code probably will be your solution.  Remember to modify it to make it suitable with your bot's codes, Don't just copy & paste it.

```
// Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
  message.member.voiceChannel.join()
    .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
      message.reply('I have successfully connected to the channel!');
    })
    .catch(console.log);
} else {
  message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
}
```

Comment: There has to be something wrong. A code must work if it has required packages and it’s right-written.

Comment: Maybe your bot doesn’t have permissions to see and connect your voice channel?

Comment: I’m not able to help you then :/

Comment: are you sure that you do everything true? because they don't seem true. You did 'msg.member.voiceChannel' instead of 'msg.author.voiceChannel' and you aren't probably using Discord.js if you still get errors.

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
let voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;
voiceChannel.join();
if (!voiceChannel) {   
    return msg.reply('Please join a voice channel before using this command.');
}
```

Comment: Ah so channel is a property of voice not `voiceChannel` - good catch