# Discord.js check if bot is in a voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a question: I want to check if the Bot is on a channel in msg.guild. I have a command `?checkchannel` that replies whether or not the bot is on a voice channel of said guild. If the bot is on one it should reply: "Is on a voice channel" and if he is not he should reply he isn't.

Thank you.

Comment: @nouvist that was not the question, i want to check if the BOT is in an voice channel, but how can i check if he is in one

Comment: ouh, didnt read your question. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple, try this:

```js
// If the bot is not connected to a voice channel, the 'channel' object should be 'undefined'
if(msg.guild.voice.cannel)
  {
    msg.channel.send(`I'm in a voice channel!`);
  }
else
  {
    console.log(`I'm not in a voice channel!`);
  }
```

##### Note:

This only checks the `channel` of the `message`, **not** if the bot is connected to **any** `voice channel` on the server!

If you want to check, if he's connected to **any** `voice channel` you should check out [Viriatos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67772686/13685706)

#### Edit:

You can also reduce [Vitiaro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67772686/13685706) to a single line:

```js
msg.guild.channels.cache.some(channel => (channel.type === 'voice' && channel.members.has(Client.user.id)) ? msg.channel.send('It is on a voice channel') : msg.channel.send('It is not on a voice channel')
```

But you have to decide for yourself whether this is clearer or not.

---

#### References:

- [Similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089293/how-to-locate-the-voice-chat-that-the-discord-bot-is-connected-to/55091225)
- [`guild#voice#channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel)

Comment: Thanks, but i need to look for all channels

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly and you want to check whether the bot is in **any** voice channel of the guild corresponding to `msg.guild`:

```js
if(msg.guild.channels.cache.some(channel => (channel.type === 'voice' && channel.members.has(Client.user.id)) {
    msg.channel.send('It is on a voice channel'); // Replies on the same channel the command was sent to
}
else {
    msg.channel.send('It is not on a voice channel');
}
```

Comment: I think you can even reduce it to one line like this: `msg.guild.channels.cache.some(channel => (channel.type === 'voice' && channel.members.has(Client.user.id)) ? msg.channel.send('It is on a voice channel') : msg.channel.send('It is not on a voice channel')`

Comment: But you have to decide for yourself whether this is clearer or not.

Comment: Yep that is cleaner. You could also first filter the cached channels to an array containing only `VoiceChannel`'s with `msg.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice')` and then do the `.some(...)` on it, could be faster.

Comment: @Viriato Probably, but I doubt that 1000 users will run this command at the same time :D I think that would save a few milliseconds. Whether it is worth it he has to decide for himself :D

Comment: @Neotastisch I updated the 'cleaner' version to my answer, looks much better there than in the comments ^^

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with the latest discord.js version (v14)

```js
if(interaction.guild.members.me.voice.channel){
   console.log("I am connected to a Voice Channel!")
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. OP doesn't even use `interaction`s.

Comment: Yes. You don't have to use opus in order to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: OP = Original Poster, i.e. the person that asked this question.